# How to use ngFor to make cards remain in a row in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, ngfor, mat-card

`ngFor` generated card stacked on each other instead of remain in a row.

I am generating cards through `ngFor`. I am using `fxFlex="30"` for each card but they stacked on each other. I used `flex-wrap` also but didn't work.

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="designs" [@expand]>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row" style="display: inline" *ngFor="let design of designs">
    <div fxFlex="30">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            <h2>{{design.label}}</h2>
          </mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>
            <h3>{{design.time}}hr</h3>
          </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="{{BaseURL + design.image}}">
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>{{design.description}}</p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions style="margin: auto;">
          <button mat-stroked-button routerLink="/contact" color="primary">Book Now</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my generated cards should be in a row. But in actual they stacked on each other.

Comment: The default `display` of a div is `block`. Change it to `inline` using `CSS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to pay attention to the minor details on the [Angular flex layout page](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayout-API). This kind of thing got me a few times when starting out since I wasn't as familiar with flex before using it.

Using `fxLayout` mostly tells the element what kind of *container* it's going to be. In this case, you probably want to move your `*ngFor` to the same div that has the `fxFlex="30"`, and with luck, you **might** be able to move them both to the card.

```
<div fxFlex *ngIf="designs" [@expand]>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-sm="row" style="display: inline">
    <div fxFlex="30" *ngFor="let design of designs">
```

Depending on what you need this for, a [Grid](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/grid) might help a lot as well.